# Cannot relate new groupby dataframe to original dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe called `differ_vt` that I wanted to apply `groupby` and summarize on the columns `'CO_FIPS'` and `'FLD_ZONE'`:

```
        FLD_ZONE    AWPOP_1   Area_SQMI_1   AWHU_1  AWPOP_2  Area_SQMI_2    AWHU_2  CO_FIPS
    0   A           18.1      23.1          101.3   3.0      23.1           3.1     50001   
    1   AE          6.7       13.5          58.6    0.03     13.5           4.8     50001   
    2   N           1.3       1.2           23.0    7.1      1.2            8.3     50001
    3   X           0.0       38.5          0.0     0.0      38.5           0.0     50001
    4   X500        4.6       44.5          4.8     4.8      44.5           2.1     50001
```

I create a new dataframe for the grouped and summarized data:

```
vt_sum = differ_vt_outer.groupby(['CO_FIPS', 'FLD_ZONE']).agg({'AWPOP_1': 'sum', 'Area_SQMI_1': 'sum', 'AWHU_1': 'sum', 'AWPOP_2': 'sum', 'Area_SQMI_2': 'sum', 'AWHU_2': 'sum'})
```

The new dataframe looks something like this:

```
vt_sum.head()
>
                  AWPOP_1   Area_SQMI_1 AWHU_1  AWPOP_2 Area_SQMI_2 AWHU_2 
CO_FIPS FLD_ZONE                        
50001   A         2335.8    79.7        1095.1  2334.0  79.7        1094.1
        AE        2134.5    74.1        1179.5  2134.5  74.1        1179.5
        N         96.8      0.2         13.1    94.0    0.2         11.7
        X         68119.7   1333.2      30623.9 68115.5 1333.2      30621.9
        X500      339.2     4.4         149.8   339.2   4.4         149.8
50003   A         1006.9    4.8         542.7   1006.9  4.8         542.7
        AE        2441.6    2.3         1265.0  2441.6  2.3         1265.0
        AO        3.1       0.0         3.5     3.1     0.0         3.5
        X         34896.6   700.4       20075.2 34896.6 700.4       20075.2
```

Now, I want to relate the summarized dataframe back to the original `diff_vt` dataframe and create new columns based on the summarized values. For example, for `CO_FIPS = 50001` and `FLD_ZONE = A`, I want to add a column called `Tot_AWPOP_1` that has a value of 2335.8.

```
differ_vt_outer['Tot_AWPOP_1'] = vt_sum['AWPOP_1'].values
```

However, when I run this, I get the error:

> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation) instead of `agg` after the `groupby` and `join` the result to the orignal dataframe after `add_prefix` to the columns' names, try:

```
list_col_sum = ['AWPOP_1', 'Area_SQMI_1', 'AWHU_1', 'AWPOP_2', 'Area_SQMI_2', 'AWHU_2']
differ_vt_outer = differ_vt_outer.join(differ_vt_outer.groupby(['CO_FIPS', 'FLD_ZONE'])[list_col_sum ]\
                                                      .transform(sum).add_prefix('Tot_'))
```

Comment: How do you like this little trick? `differ_vt_outer.assign(**differ_vt_outer.groupby(['CO_FIPS','FLD_ZONE']).agg('sum').add_prefix('Tot_').reset_index())`

Comment: @ScottBoston with the given example it seems to work as actually using `agg` or `transform` does the same (no aggregation to do with the input really), but it seems to fail if you replace some values before like `differ_vt_outer.loc[1,['FLD_ZONE', 'CO_FIPS']] = differ_vt_outer.loc[0,['FLD_ZONE', 'CO_FIPS']].values`? or you meant to use `transform` in your method without the `reset_index`? ;)